# The standard deviation of the mean of the means

Tags: variance, mean, standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics, sample

I have 8 means referring to 8 groups. Since I have the numerosity of each group, I can calculate the mean of the means. How can I calculate the standard deviation of the mean of the means?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with doing this?

Comment: It can be important to know whether the data of each group are independent or not, if it is the case, what you might want is the sample standard deviation between group of ANOVA model.